# Webscraping using a DOM updated using Javascript/Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, web-scraping

I am wanting to gather data for educational use from a website. Basically statistics based web development. Anyways, the site I want to gather data from uses Javascript/Ajax to update numbers on their site. I'm interested to hear some ideas others have on gathering data of this form. If I grab the source no data is initially contained. I have looked at XQuery which may be useful if I can get the updated DOM tree but not until then. I can see the tree being updated by Firebug in Firefox but what is an easy way of getting the code from there, or other sources? Thanks for any direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complicated the website is, you might be able to bypass the need to use javascript. Take a look at the ajax requests as they show up in Firebug. If they're predictable, like for example always `/getData?item_id=123`, then you can probably just scrape the data with a scripting language of your choice.

Comment: So what you are basically saying is hijack their ajax request, which could be done with any language offering javascript running support? I looked into this but it may be a bit harder since they track all connections, even those not logged in with a cookie. I'll look into it further, thank you.

Comment: @ars You don't really need javascript. An AJAX request is just an HTTP request. You can make sure the HTTP headers you send look the same like the ones in Firebug, and you should get the same response. You can use perl, python, ruby, or even curl/wget.